# OCCI resultset getString() method returning nullpointer error

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I'm getting the below error when trying to fetch a string value from a column in the current row ( `rs->getString(2)` ):

```
Unhandled exception at 0x61d4336f (msvcp100d.dll) in OCCITest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.
```

For example, I'm using `rs->getInt(1)` to fetch the ID of the current row, and it works perfectly. (although I still got the above error when I tried to fetch it as a string)

The values in the database are varchar2 type, so I guess it should be returned as a string value. Anyone has any idea what could be the problem?

-Win10 64-bit
-Visual studio 2010
-Oracle db 11.2.0.2.0 64-bit
-Oracle instant client 64-bit
-building a 64-bit application

Comment: did you try `your_variable.tostring();`

Comment: looks like the problem was that I used the oraocci11.lib instead of oraocci11d.lib, now that I switched it runs perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

to see other people this question with answer:

as you say:

you can use `oraocci11.lib instead of oraocci11d.lib,`